# Firebase - Custom Authentication

Tags: firebase-authentication

I'm a total n00b to Firebase. Is it possible to collect the user Id and password from Firebase's authentication layer and use it to do my own authentication (against a store that's in my company's network)? If so, how do I go about doing this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You would add a form that would ask for the user's credentials, and pass the username and password to Firebase to authentication. If the authentication is successful, you get a token. You then allow the user to enter your system.

Comment: OK. But, how would I take those credentials and check them against a system that's behind our firewall? More specifically, we have SAP on-prem and I'd need to get the credentials to check against SAP. Or in this scenario is using Firebase overkill and would we just need to handle authentication ourselves? I'm a bit confused on how to do this.

Comment: Is the purpose to to allow people to access a private service from the Internet? You could first require users to login using a private login page on your Intranet, auth using Firebase, and store the token in your DB. Then when the user wants to access the service from the Internet, have a separate login page, authenticate using Firebase, but check if the token matches any stored token. If nothing matches, reject the user.